# Azure databricks -- an empty dataframe throwing error for count() method

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am seeing almost 90% time failure in while making a count call on a dataframe. The sample code and error is provided below. Some other observation is that this is happening when there is supposed to be no rows in the dataframe. The dataframe has one complex datatype of map type.

Any pointers why this is happening and how to resolve it.

````
              openOrdersObject
              .filter(col("executionId") == executionId )
              .alias("OO")
              .join(finalDF.alias("fdf"), (  col("OO.executionId") == col("fdf.executionId") )
                            &( col("OO.SRC_SYS_CD") == col("fdf.SRC_SYS_CD") )
                            &( col("OO.SLS_ORD_NO") == col("fdf.SLS_ORD_NO") )
                            &( col("OO.SLS_ORD_LN_NO") == col("fdf.SLS_ORD_LN_NO") )
                    ,"left_outer"    
               )
               .filter( col("fdf.KitFlagBoolean") == True  )  
               .select(
                         col("fdf.SRC_SYS_CD").alias("SRC_SYS_CD"),
                         lit(sector).alias("sector"),                                  
                         col("fdf.executionId").alias("ExecutionID"),
                         col("OO.SLS_ORD_NO"),
                         col("OO.SLS_ORD_LN_NO"),
                         col("OO.SCHD_LN_NO"),
                         lit(jobType).alias("jobType"),
                         lit(None).alias("CreditHoldFlag"),
                         lit(None).alias("HeaderDeliveryBlockFlag"),
                         lit(None).alias("ItemDeliveryBlockFlag"), 
                         lit(None).alias("CustomBlocksFlag"),
                         lit(None).alias("ExceptionDateInBlankReason"),
                         lit(None).alias("HardAllocatedFlag"),
                         lit(None).alias("BatchSerialNumberFlag"),
                         lit(None).alias("DropShipmentFlag"),
                         col("fdf.KitFlagBoolean").alias("KitFlag"),
                         lit(None).alias("MymedisetFlag"),
                         lit(None).alias("MTOFlag"),
                         lit(None).alias("DiscontinuedMaterialFlag"),
                         lit(None).alias("DChainStatusNotActiveFlag"),
                         lit(None).alias("DeliveryInFullFlag"),
                         lit(None).alias("OrderGroupingFlag"),
                         lit(None).alias("SameDayShipmentFlag"),
                         lit(None).alias("RecommendedDateInThePastFlag"),
                         col("fdf.skipProcessing").alias("skipProcessing"),
                         col("fdf.finalCustomData").alias("customData"),
                         lit(current_timestamp()).alias("createdTime"),
                         lit(current_timestamp()).alias("updatedTime")
               )
               
)
 
print(dfToWrite.count())```

**Error is below **

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7967.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 7967.0 (TID 64310) (10.67.175.90 executor 30): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 30 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-2927235158406932> in <module>
     43 )
     44 
---> 45 print(dfToWrite.count())
     46 CommonUtils.updateSkipFlag(
     47   dfToWrite, ["KitFlag", "customData", "skipProcessing", "updatedTime"], environment

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in count(self)
    668         2
    669         """
--> 670         return int(self._jdf.count())
    671 
    672     def collect(self):

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    115     def deco(*a, **kw):
    116         try:
--> 117             return f(*a, **kw)
    118         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    119             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

/databricks/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

**Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o1395.count.**
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 7967.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 7967.0 (TID 64310) (10.67.175.90 executor 30): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 30 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN messages.
Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2765)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2712)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2706)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2706)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1255)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1255)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1255)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2973)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2914)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2902)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:1028)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJobInternal(SparkContext.scala:2446)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.runSparkJobs(Collector.scala:264)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector.collect(Collector.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:82)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.Collector$.collect(Collector.scala:88)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.collect.InternalRowFormat$.collect(cachedSparkResults.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.$anonfun$getOrComputeResultInternal$1(ResultCacheManager.scala:512)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResultInternal(ResultCacheManager.scala:511)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:399)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.ResultCacheManager.getOrComputeResult(ResultCacheManager.scala:374)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollectResult(SparkPlan.scala:389)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at com.databricks.sql.execution.UnionWithLocalDataExec.executeCollect(OptimizeLocalUnion.scala:71)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.SmallTableCache.$anonfun$withStatsDatasetCache$1(SmallTableCache.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.SmallTableCache.$anonfun$withStatsDatasetCache$1$adapted(SmallTableCache.scala:60)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.computeIfAbsent(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1660)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.SmallTableCache.withStatsDatasetCache(SmallTableCache.scala:60)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.SmallTableCache.withStats(SmallTableCache.scala:83)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.SmallTableCache.withStats$(SmallTableCache.scala:83)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.Snapshot.withStats(Snapshot.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.DataSkippingReaderV2.getDataSkippedFiles(DataSkippingReaderV2.scala:236)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.DataSkippingReaderV2.getDataSkippedFiles$(DataSkippingReaderV2.scala:232)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.SnapshotEdge.getDataSkippedFiles(SnapshotEdge.scala:50)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.DataSkippingReader.$anonfun$filesForScan$12(DataSkippingReader.scala:512)
    at com.databricks.sql.acl.CheckPermissions$.trusted(CheckPermissions.scala:1258)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.DataSkippingReader.$anonfun$filesForScan$5(DataSkippingReader.scala:512)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.FrameProfiler$.record(FrameProfiler.scala:80)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.$anonfun$recordDeltaOperation$5(DeltaLogging.scala:115)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$recordOperation$4(UsageLogging.scala:434)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.$anonfun$withAttributionContext$1(UsageLogging.scala:240)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext(UsageLogging.scala:235)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionContext$(UsageLogging.scala:232)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionContext(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags(UsageLogging.scala:279)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.withAttributionTags$(UsageLogging.scala:271)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.withAttributionTags(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogging.scala:415)
    at com.databricks.logging.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogging.scala:341)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:19)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.PublicDBLogging.recordOperation0(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:56)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:129)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:70)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogger.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:57)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.recordOperation(DatabricksSparkUsageLogger.scala:85)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation(UsageLogger.scala:402)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.UsageLogging.recordOperation$(UsageLogger.scala:381)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.Snapshot.recordOperation(Snapshot.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation(DeltaLogging.scala:113)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.metering.DeltaLogging.recordDeltaOperation$(DeltaLogging.scala:97)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.Snapshot.recordDeltaOperation(Snapshot.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.DataSkippingReader.filesForScan(DataSkippingReader.scala:496)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.DataSkippingReader.filesForScan$(DataSkippingReader.scala:452)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.Snapshot.filesForScan(Snapshot.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.PrepareDeltaScan.$anonfun$filesForScan$3(PrepareDeltaScan.scala:160)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.PrepareDeltaScan.$anonfun$filesForScan$1(PrepareDeltaScan.scala:160)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:377)
    at com.databricks.backend.daemon.driver.ProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:363)
    at com.databricks.spark.util.SparkDatabricksProgressReporter$.withStatusCode(ProgressReporter.scala:34)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.util.DeltaProgressReporterEdge.withStatusCode(DeltaProgressReporterEdge.scala:30)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.util.DeltaProgressReporterEdge.withStatusCode$(DeltaProgressReporterEdge.scala:25)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.PrepareDeltaScan.withStatusCode(PrepareDeltaScan.scala:62)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.PrepareDeltaScan.com$databricks$sql$transaction$tahoe$stats$PrepareDeltaScan$$filesForScan(PrepareDeltaScan.scala:140)
    at com.databricks.sql.transaction.tahoe.stats.PrepareDeltaScan$$anonfun$1.$anonfun$applyOrElse$2(PrepareDeltaScan.scala:184)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:852)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$4(SQLExecution.scala:326)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$3(SQLExecution.scala:326)
    at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$2(SQLExecution.scala:325)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withOptimisticTransaction(SQLExecution.scala:343)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withThreadLocalCaptured$1(SQLExecution.scala:324)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.$anonfun$run$1(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingHelper.runWithCaptured$(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:54)
    at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.runWithCaptured(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.util.threads.SparkThreadLocalCapturingRunnable.run(SparkThreadLocalForwardingThreadPoolExecutor.scala:104)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
````

Comment: What happens when you run `print(dfToWrite.selectExpr('1').count())` instead of `print(dfToWrite.count())` ?

Comment: What has it got to do with azure or databricks?